# Azure form recognizer app invalid resource name

Tags: azure, api, docker, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I'm traying to daploy an instance of the form recognizer app in Azure. For that I'm following the instructions in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/deploy-label-tool

I have created the docker instance and the connection, but the step to create the APP is failing. 
This are the parameters I'm using:

```
Display Name: Test-form
Source Connection: <previuosly created connection>
Folder Path: None
Form Recognizer Service Uri: https://XXX-test.cognitiveservices.azure.com/
API Key: XXXXX
Description: None
```

And this is the error and getting:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried naming the project differently? It looks like you are using characters in the name that are not supported.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. It turned out to be due to incorrect SAS URI formatting because I generated and copied the SAS token via the Storage Accounts interface. It's much easier to get the correct format for the SAS URI if you generate it through the Storage Explorer (currently in Preview) as opposed to through the Storage Accounts.

If you read the documentation carefully it gives you a step by step guide

"To retrieve the SAS URL, open the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer, right-click your container, and select Get shared access signature. Set the expiry time to some time after you'll have used the service. Make sure the Read, Write, Delete, and List permissions are checked, and click Create. Then copy the value in the URL section. It should have the form: https://.blob.core.windows.net/?"

[Form Recognizer Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/label-tool?tabs=v2-0#connect-to-the-sample-labeling-tool)

Answer (score 0):

The error messages point to a configuration issue with the AzureBlobStorageTemplate Thing. Most likely the containerName field for the Blob Storage Thing is empty or contains invalid characters

Ensure the containerName is a valid Azure storage container name.

Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Naming-and-Referencing-Containers--Blobs--and-Metadata for more information.

A container name must be a valid DNS name

The Connector loads and caches all configuration settings during startup. Any changes that you make to the configuration when troubleshooting are ignored until the Connector is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the container connection, you must add the container into the SAS URI, such as

`https://<storage-account>.blob.core.windows.net/<Enter-My-Container-Here>?<SAS Key>`

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly use the open source labeling tool, please see the section further down in the doc:
The OCR Form Labeling Tool is also available as an open-source project on GitHub. The tool is a web application built using React + Redux, and is written in TypeScript. To learn more or contribute, see OCR Form Labeling Tool.